# How to store and handle the window

Tags: c++

im am a beginner
first, I wanna use this HWND hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderRT6FormDC", BlueStack") to get hwnd program that i want get.
and How to store and handle the BlueStack window when it have more than 2 BlueStack,

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderRT6FormDC", BlueStack");
        DWORD pid;
        float temp = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
```

Comment: You could put them in a `std::vector<HWND>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `EnumWindows()` to get a list of all windows, get the class name and the title and compare them to filter out anything that doesn't match your search queries

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

static BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowCallback(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) 
{
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    char* title = new char[length + 1];
    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, length + 1);

    char classname[200]{ 0 };

    GetClassName(hWnd, classname, 200);

    if (!_stricmp("BlueStack", title) && !_stricmp("ThunderRT6FormDC", classname))
    {
        std::cout << hWnd << ":  " << title << " class name: " << classname << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] title;
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enmumerating windows..." << std::endl;
    EnumWindows(enumWindowCallback, NULL);
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

This will output all windows which match